# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: error-handling

I have simple html site. how I can fix the problem 'The requested URL was not found on this server' when user gives wrong URL. for example user type mydomain.com/abc.html and this page is not exist on server, so it will cause an error. how to redirect it on error page to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file and add this line.

`ErrorDocument 404 /foo.html`

This will redirect any 404 error to foo.html

Comment: I have add the full path with command like ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/mysite/error.php and it works fine. thanks